# Web Accessibility : Input need to check with keyboard Enter key pressed

Tags: java, html, jquery, css, web

I created an accordion with pure CSS and its expand when I click with the mouse. But when I navigate to this accordion with the keyboard Tab and hit the Enter key the accordion not expanding. I want to open the accordion with pressing the Enter key. code below

```
<div class="sc-accordion">
      <input class="sc-accordion__input" type="checkbox" id="one"/>
      <label class="sc-accordion__label" for="one">Accordion Heading</label>
      <div class="sc-accordion__content">
        Accordion Content
      </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).on('keypress', 'input', function(e) {
  $(this).prop("checked",!($(this).is(':checked')));
  if(e.keyCode == 13 && e.target.type !== 'submit') {
    $(".sc-accordion__content").toggle();
  }
});
```

```css
.sc-accordion__content{
  display:none;
}
p{
  color:#666;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>Please try both enter both TAB and ENTER</p>

<div class="sc-accordion">
    <input class="sc-accordion__input" type="checkbox" id="one"/>
    <label class="sc-accordion__label" for="one">Accordion Heading</label>
    <div class="sc-accordion__content">
      Accordion Content
    </div>
</div>
```